# how to write something of something and something

Tags: grammatical-number

I'm confused whether should I use plural when writing something of something and something.

> For example: the dataset of A and B (A and B are the names of the
>   dataset).

Should I use plural for 'dataset' here? My understanding is like this:

> 'the dataset of A and B' equals 'the dataset of A and the dataset of B'

So I should use singular for the 'dataset'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mary and John each has their own respective car:

> The cars of Mary and John

Mary and John share the same car

> The car of Mary and John.

*Mary and John* is the name of a single car

> The car *Mary and John*

The car has two names, either Mary or John

> The car Mary or John

Choose one car from two cars

> The cars Mary or John
>   A car Mary or John

---

Concerning the datasets ...

A and B each has their own respective dataset:

> The datasets of A and B

A and B share the same dataset

> The dataset of A and B.

*A and B* is the name of a single dataset

> The dataset *A_and_B*

The dataset has two names, either A or B

> The dataset A or B

Choose one dataset from two datasets

> The datasets A or B
>   A dataset A or B

Comment: Mary and John each *has*??

Comment: Iterate thro the list of mary, ..., and john, where each member has ... For this case, there are only two members in the list.

Comment: Our employees each has a company issued tablet - for case where the list are all the employees in the company.

Comment: I had not bothered to explain that this is point-form disjointed structure.

Comment: This feels very wrong to me, but you argue it like it should be common knowledge so now you've got me wondering whether it's just something I never learned properly.  But in my mind it's: "Mary and John each have," "They each have," "Each member has," "Our employees each have," "Each employee has," "Each one has," "Each of them has"

Comment: Perhaps, there is a confusion between "*We **still** have a phone*" vs "*We **each** has/have a phone*" vs "*We have a phone **each***". Perhaps, you are right - we need to treat *each* as adverb to the verb *have*, rather than as a pronoun/adjective. {They still have a phone each} == {They each have phone still} ??